# parsing table of content into csv file with python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv

I have several html files from an ocr scanning of a book's table of content. 
My aim is to parse them, extract some of the data and eventually store the data in a csv file.
The structure of the data is similar to this:

```
Location_1 - id.

Name_1 - year_1 - case_1, case_2, case_3 ...
       - year_2 - case_1, case_2, case_3 ...

Name_2 - year_1 - case_1, case_2, case_3 ...

Name_3 - year_1 - case_1, case_2, ...
       - year_2 - case_1, case_2, ...
       - year_3 - num1, num2, ...
```

The files are irregular, so I can't rely on line breaks or html tags to split the content.

So far I have followed a top down approach:

1) retrieved location and id with regular expressions
2) used the locations as indices to split the text in smaller chunks to get the names (with a function)
3) retrieved the names with another regular expression.
4) use zip function to create a list of places, id.s, names

At this point I feel stuck and can't come with a decent solution to get a hierarchically ordered structure that includes the inner nodes (years and case numbers).

Reading around seems that regex are not the best tool for this kind of parsing and it's better to use grammars, but I couldn't find 'real world examples'.

So my question is: which is the optimal solution to parse table of contents keeping the hierarchical order and in a way that makes it possible to build a csv file out of them (the csv file should have one case per row)?

EDIT:

this is an extract of the text

> **Hulskov, Eltang s., Brusk h.(1).** — H, 36.
>
> *Jes Nielsen, 1636: 131.*
>
> *Kirsten Hansdatter, 1636: 131.*
>
> **Hulvig, Hodde s., Øster Home h.** — H, 37.
>
> *Christen Hansen Smed, 1637: 569, 571, 580, 625, 808, 1638: 21, 128.*

The parts in bold are locations and they are always at the start of the line and followed by a char + digit code. On the other lines (in italic) there are names followed by one (or more) year and then some case numbers after the colon.

This is the core structure although in the rest of the text there are several irregularities.

I could extract most of the location names, char + digits codes and names and I could set them in a zip list on order to mantain the hyerarchical order, but I couldn't find a decent solution to bind years and cases to each name.

Comment: If a line is `Cambridge - 2013`, how do you know if it's a `Location - id` or a  `Name - Year` line?  Perhaps an example input document would help--one with more than one type of each record.

Comment: I will add an extract of the text. In my case all names are either name+surname or emdash+surname, while the name of the locations are always located at the start of a string and followed by a character+number code.

Comment: To store the years and case numbers, it seems like you can use a dict-of-lists, where the keys are years, and the values are lists of case numbers.  Is there more to your question?

Comment: What I don't get is how to keep the correspondent order with all the elements. I should print a csv file out of it with, so the dict should be something like {location1 : {nameq : {year1 : [case1, case2, case3], year2: [...]}, name2 : {year1 ...}} location2: {...}} ans so forth. I can't make it for the last part of the work, at least if I keep using regular expression which worked for the first part.